# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n \leq \lim_{n \to\infty}y_n.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Suppose $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are two convergent sequences such that infinitely many of the terms satisfy $x_n \leq y_n$. Prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n \leq \displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n.$

My attempt: Since $x_n \leq y_n$ holds for infinitely many $n$, by choosing subsequence, we can assume that $x_n \leq y_n$ holds for all $n$. We can also assume that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are convergent. Therefore, $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \leq \displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n.$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Using argument by contradiction.

Comment: Your attempt looks pretty good indeed, yet instead of  "We can also assume...", you could more accurately write "We **know that** ..." . Also, a sequence converges iff *any subsequence* converges to same limit as the sequence

Comment: Your attempt is quasi-circular, you just traded "infinitely many" for "all", but the main claim remains unchanged.

Comment: You are wrong; one can be less than the other for infinitely many terms but still not be for all terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**, by contraposition:

- suppose that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n > \displaystyle\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n$;
- you can then find an $N$ such that $x_n > y_n$ for all $n > N$;
- but then $x_n \le y_n$ can only hold for at most $N$ and thus finitely many $n$.

Comment: $x_n>y_n$ for infinitely many $n$ doesn't contradict that $x_n\le y_n$ for infinitely many $n$. However, what you proved does suffice: $x_n>y_n$ for all $n\ge N$, so $x_n\le y_n$ for at most $N<\infty$ values of $n$, namely $n\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}$.

Comment: @CodyJohnson Of course, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The terms that satisfy the condition form a subsequence. Clearly the subsequential limit has lim x_n <= lim y_n . But this is just the limit of the sequences because the sequences converge.